# Airbyte MySQL to Snowflake ingestion not working as expected

Tags: airbyte

When I did a POC on Airbyte earlier this year, Airbyte would create **AIRBYTE_RAW** table in the destination schema and create the normalized table (if I selected normalization as Normalized tabular data) in the destination schema. Last week, I returned to Airbyte to create a MYSQL<->Snowflake connection and found that the raw data is being landed in **airbyte_internal** schema that was created on the fly and data is normalized into a table in the destination schema even though I select Raw data (JSON). I looked up articles/blogs/Airbyte slack channel for a reference to this changed behavior and could not find any. What happened? Can anybody shed some light?